# How can i change column of a df to index of the df?

Tags: python-3.x, date, dataframe, indexing

I have a "Date" column in my df and I wish to use it as the index of df

Date values in 'Date' column are in the correct format as per DateTime (yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 0):

Using set_index we can a column index of the df

df.set_index('Date')